# How to make gmail like search box with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement input field with additional options similar to gmail search box. You can see it on the screenshots below.

[image]

When you click on a caret sign then additional form is shown up:

[image]

Currently, I'm struggling with making a nice looking form shown after clicking on the caret sign. Anyone knows how to achieve that with Bootstrap?

Here is a jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1sfs9xb/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <li>
            <form action="#" class="form-horizontal">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Input 1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="input1" type="text" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="name">Input2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                      <input class="form-control" id="name" name="input2" type="text" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>
                <input class="btn action-button pull-right" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save">
              </p>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Some content</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a little CSS and JS:

CSS (your dropdown menu is relative to `input-group-btn` so you have to change position of that to static - now your dropdown menu is related to the `input-group`):

```
.input-group-btn {
  position: static;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
}
```

JS (get width of the input and assign it to your dropdown menu, also change it on browser resize):

```
var inputWidth = $('.form-control').outerWidth();
$('.dropdown-menu').css('width', inputWidth);
$(window).resize(function () {
    inputWidth = $('.form-control').outerWidth();
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('width', inputWidth);
});
```

### **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x1sfs9xb/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for!